# Drawing arrows on sides of a node

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, flow-charts

I'm stuck a little with TikZ, I've this example where I would like to add `Yes` /`No` arrows on the right and left sides of the `Finished?` block. So far, the arrows show over the block also the spacing is too narrow. I'll be grateful for any help.

## MWE

```
% vim:ft=tex:
%
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% UML diagram generation
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, shapes, positioning}
% \usetikzlibrary{fit, backgrounds, matrix, arrows.meta} % Optional widgets for background
\usepackage{caption}

% Define drawing set
\tikzset{%
  >={Latex[width=2mm,length=2mm]},
  % Specifications for style of nodes:
            base/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, draw=black, minimum width=4cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, font=\sffamily},
  activityStarts/.style = {base, fill=blue!30},
       startstop/.style = {base, fill=red!30},
    activityRuns/.style = {base, fill=green!30},
         process/.style = {base, minimum width=2.5cm, fill=orange!15, font=\ttfamily},
    decision/.style = {diamond, rounded corners, draw=black, fill=green!10, text centered, font=\sffamily}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm, every node/.style={fill=white, font=\sffamily}, align=center]
    \node (start)             [activityStarts]                      {Application starts};
    \node (onTextInput)       [process, below of=start]             {procedureA()};
    \node (computeStuff)         [process, below of=onTextInput]        {procedureB};
    \node (runningProcess)   [activityRuns, below of=computeStuff]      {Compute x};
    \node (decideStuff)   [decision, below=0.5cm of runningProcess] {Finished?};
    \node (createOutput)      [process, below of=decideStuff]           {addd};

    \draw[->] (start)       --  (onTextInput);
    \draw[->] (onTextInput) --  (computeStuff);
    \draw[->] (computeStuff)   --   (runningProcess);
    \draw[->] (runningProcess) --  (decideStuff);   
    \draw[->] (decideStuff) |-  node {No} (runningProcess);     
    \draw[->] (runningProcess) --  (createOutput);  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Compile

```
latexmk -pdf -xelatex tikz-example.tex
```

## Explanation and desired outcome

[image: Output with desired arrows marked]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not mix `below=of` with `below of=` syntax, i.e. avoid the latter. And one can use `chains` (which loads `positioning`) here to avoid unnecessary repetition.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, chains,shapes.geometric}

% Define drawing set
\tikzset{%
  >={Latex[width=2mm,length=2mm]},
  % Specifications for style of nodes:
            base/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, draw=black, minimum width=4cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, font=\sffamily},
  activityStarts/.style = {base, fill=blue!30},
       startstop/.style = {base, fill=red!30},
    activityRuns/.style = {base, fill=green!30},
         process/.style = {base, minimum width=2.5cm, fill=orange!15, font=\ttfamily},
    decision/.style = {diamond, rounded corners, draw=black, fill=green!10, text centered, font=\sffamily}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.5cm]
 \begin{scope}[start chain=going below, 
    nodes={fill=white, font=\sffamily, align=center,on chain,join=by ->}]
    \node (start)             [activityStarts]                      {Application starts};
    \node (onTextInput)       [process]             {procedureA()};
    \node (computeStuff)         [process]        {procedureB};
    \node (runningProcess)   [activityRuns]      {Compute x};
    \node (decideStuff)   [decision, below] {Finished?};
 \end{scope}
 \node (createOutput)      [process,below=of decideStuff]           {add};
 \draw[->,rounded corners=2pt] (decideStuff) -- ++ (3,0) |-  node[pos=0.25,right] {No} (runningProcess);     
 \draw[->,rounded corners=2pt] (decideStuff) -- ++ (-3,0) |-  node[pos=0.25,left] {Yes} (createOutput);     
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, answer, thank you. Could you kindly explain what's the role of `-- ++` syntax?

Comment: @Konrad `-- ++ (x,y)` means "draw a straight line to the current position (in the path) + `(x,y)`". In this very case one could also use  `-- + (x,y)` because this is also the start position of the path plus `(x,y)`.